# NotebookEvaluate via URL - or Google Drive format

Tags: import, notebooks, cloud-deploy

Is there an option or other method to run `EvaluateNotebook` for remote notebooks, ie EvaluateNotebook[url-to-notebook] in other words evaluate remote notebooks in local kernel?

The current version does not seem to support this, and neither does
 `EvaluateNotebook[Import[url-to-notebook]]`

In a test I tried to evaluate a notebook by sharing a Google Drive link - the file was set to read access for anyone with the link. However

In the first case gives Syntax errors due to some Google-related meta-name

```
Syntax::sntxb: 
   Expression cannot begin with 
    "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google"
       content="notranslate"><meta <<6820>>ck-m7k",0,"/
       drive/v2beta",0,0,1,[0,0,0]”.
```

In the second case gives

```
NotebookEvaluate::nbnfnd: Unable to find the notebook .
```

I've tried many `$ImportFormats` in `Import` in addition to default, eg `HTML`, `Text`, `String`, `JSON`, `RawJSON` etc, but these all return empty data.